# Remember field data until submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on a MVC web applciation.

I've created a ViewModel for my HTML Form and passing it to the View.

I want to know if there is a way i can hold data that users enter until they submit the form? The following scenario is what I'm trying to achieve.

Scenario:

Login --> Go to the Form Page --> Fill form (user data) --> do not submit --> Close browser/log out--> Login/open browser again --> Go to the Form Page --> Data entered from last session is still present.

Is there a way i can achieve this?

I'm not using ViewBag or Session to load the Form data/labels/input-fields(drop-down) on the page.Everything is passed through the ViewModel.

I'm looking into DataAnnotaions but not sure which one i need to use.
Cookies are least desirable but will go for it no other solution is available.

Cheers

Comment: If user doesn't submit, there is no way to store it using server technology like asp.net mvc. Try browser cache introduced in HTML5 http://html5doctor.com/storing-data-the-simple-html5-way-and-a-few-tricks-you-might-not-have-known/

Comment: @Marcel : Well I'm less inclined for Cookies. I want that to be my last option if nothing else is available.

Comment: Both of these possibilities still have faults though, a user could very easily disable cookies, or a user could be on a browser version that's too old to properly support HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't submit the form, the data will never get to the server and you won't be able to do anything server-side to store the data.

Your only alternative is to store the data client-side.  For this, you have 2 options:

1. Cookies.  jQuery.cookie is a very easy-to-use tool for this, or
2. HTML5 local storage.

**EDIT:**

You could send the data behind the scenes to the server using an ajax call.  Technically, this isn't "submitting" the form.

So once the data changes (preferably after some delay), using Javascript, you could upload the current content to the server using Ajax for later retrieval.  It think this is how some sites like SO save "drafts" of content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ajax, JQuery, or JavaScript to save the state of the page in the back end. When the user logs in again, you can check the state and retrieve the data for that use accordingly accordingly.